# Answerer not responding to commenters

Tags: discussion, flagging, etiquette

In the [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098561/values-of-f-pi-4-and-f-pi-4-if-int-0xftdt-frac-12x2x-sin2/1098604#1098604) answer, the user answered the question wrongly. However, even after commenting asking the user to revise his answer, he did not comply. I have flagged this answer, but I was wondering:

> What should be the general action on such answers and such users who [do not listen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067210/homotopy-type-theory-prerequisites/1067234#1067234) to commenters?

Comment: You need to make your comment more precise. As it is written, it does not imply that the answer in question is incorrect, but rather than *one of the two answers is incorrect*. A better comment might be to point out the answerer's mistake. This is, most likely, useful to both of you.

Comment: (Also, I would not downvote the answer unless I was sure of their mistake. So then, why wouldn't I tell them why I was sure?)

Answer (score 16):

> I have flagged this answer

That is not a proper course of action. Expect the flag to be declined, either by reviewers (if it was VLQ/NAA) or by a moderator (if it was for mod attention).

> What should be the general action on such answers

Comment; downvote; (optionally) post a better answer; move on.

Users are under no obligation to respond to comments. I, for one, frequently ignore the comments left on my answers.

Comment: One might add that, particularly when the post isn't as long, trusted users can vote to delete it.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I do not understand why you mention the length of the post; the length seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: @quid In principle, it is. Yet I feel less comfortable deleting something someone has worked on for an extended period of time than a two-line answer that is obviously wrong. I would be inclined to increase the time given to an answerer to fix their post as it gets longer.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I see. I took the "can" as a technical statement.